# When I use thread and mutex, C++ occur Memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I want store integer to write_odd_queue, then popping integer from another thread.

`data_prepation_thread` function will store integer to `write_odd_queue`.

`handle_odd` function will pop integer from `write_odd_queue`.

When I write `Sleep(10)`, memory will not increase.

When I comment this code, memory will increase.

Please help me solve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

queue<int> write_odd_queue;

mutex write_odd_mutux;

void handle_odd()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int i;
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk(write_odd_mutux);
            if (!write_odd_queue.empty())
            {
                i = write_odd_queue.front();
                write_odd_queue.pop();
                cout << "test size " << write_odd_queue.empty() << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        cout << "odd " << i << endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }
}


void data_prepation_thread()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        i++;
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(write_odd_mutux);
        write_odd_queue.push(i);
        lk.unlock();
        // comment Sleep(10), memory will not increase.
        //Sleep(10);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> vec;

    thread t1(handle_odd);
    vec.push_back(move(t1));

    data_prepation_thread();

    auto it = vec.begin();
    for (; it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop that's pushing data into the queue as fast as possible - I can see why slowing it down substantially would make a difference to the memory usage.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth I don't understand your answer. Could you give me more detail.

Comment: This is not a memory leak, but memory consumption of a container when you push data faster than it is consumed. You slow thread that push data and memory consumption obviously decrease, what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing things from the queue with a delay of 500 milliseconds, and pushing them on to the queue with no delay - this means the queue will grow, as the frequency of your pops is not matching that of your  pushes. Adding a delay to the pushes will reduce the growth, so that it may not be obvious for short runs of the program.

Comment: I understand your explanation. Is there a good solution to solve this question?

Comment: Get rid of both sleeps, or make them the same duration, or make your popping code loop until the queue is empty.

Comment: Actually I get rid of both sleeps, but the memory will increase.

Comment: Yes, it probably will, as the popping code is more complex (and so probably slower) than the pushing code. In which case use the loop solution.

Comment: loop is good solution. I will look a better solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: @lens problem is that you use `sleep()` instead of proper synchronization, which should be done through `std::condition_variable`

Comment: @Slava Actually I use `condition_variable`，but this can well solve this problem.

Comment: @lens you can use yet another conditional variable to control size of queue. Usually in real program it is not a problem as thread pool consumes data faster than it is pushed.But if that is the case additional var would solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution to avoid `Sleep()` in both functions using condition variables:

```
queue<int> write_odd_queue;

mutex write_odd_mutux;
condition_variable data_ready;
condition_variable queue_ready;
bool stopped = false;

const size_t max_size = 1024;
const size_t min_size = 512;

void handle_odd()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(write_odd_mutux);
    while (!stopped)
    {
        if( write_odd_queue.empty() ) {
            data_ready.wait( lk );
            continue;
        }
        int i = write_odd_queue.front();
        write_odd_queue.pop();
        if( write_odd_queue.size() == min_size )
            queue_ready.notify_one();

        cout << "test size " << write_odd_queue.empty() << " ";
        lk.unlock();
        cout << "odd " << i << endl;
        lk.lock();
    }
}

void data_prepation_thread()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!stopped)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(write_odd_mutux);
        if( write_odd_queue.size() >= max_size ) {
            queue_ready.wait( lk );
            continue;
        }
        write_odd_queue.push(++i);
        if( write_odd_queue.size() == 1 )
            data_ready.notify_all();
    }
}

void stop()
{
     unique_lock<mutex> lk(write_odd_mutux);
     stopped = true;
     data_ready.notify_all();
     queue_ready.notify_all();
}
```

This will prevent queue to grow bigger than `max_size` and reenable pushing when size drops to `min_size`. Also there is no unnecessary delay in processing would be involved, as you would have with `Sleep(500)`.